# Using where all on linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am trying to implement a search function for my application, but what i want to happen is to send all the list if there is no keyword specified and i have a `where` clause.

Here is my action:

```
Public ActionResult classes(string keyword ="")
{
        EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();

        List<classlist> asd = (from subj in emp.Subjects
                               join prof in emp.professors on subj.id equals prof.id
                               join dep in emp.departments on prof.id equals dep.id
                               where subj.subj == keyword
                               select new classlist()
                               {
                                   id = subj.id,
                                   subj = subj.subj,
                                   days = subj.days,
                                   cstart = subj.cstart,
                                   cend = subj.cend,
                                   units = subj.units,
                                   fname = prof.fname,
                                   lname = prof.lname,
                                   status = prof.status,
                                   department = dep.dname,
                                   isSelected = false
                               }).ToList();

        return View(asd);
}
```

I researched about it and it says to use 'ALL' but it doesn't work. I don't want to make an if else statement depending if the keyword is empty or no since that will make my code ugly. The `subj` property is the name of the subject.

Comment: you would add an OR to your where clause, written  || String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like this

```
where subj.subj == keyword || keyword==""
```

Or this, so that you don't need a separate `where`

```
from subj in emp.Subjects.Where(x=>x.subj == keyword || keyword=="")
join prof in emp.professors.....
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer provided by @DarkKnight, you can also leverage the fact that the query isn't actually executed until you materialise it with `ToList`, so you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult classes(string keyword ="")
{
    EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();

    IEnumerable<classlist> asd = (from subj in emp.Subjects
                           join prof in emp.professors on subj.id equals prof.id
                           join dep in emp.departments on prof.id equals dep.id
                           select new classlist()
                           {
                               id = subj.id,
                               subj = subj.subj,
                               days = subj.days,
                               cstart = subj.cstart,
                               cend = subj.cend,
                               units = subj.units,
                               fname = prof.fname,
                               lname = prof.lname,
                               status = prof.status,
                               department = dep.dname,
                               isSelected = false
                           });

    //Apply the where clause if required
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
        asd = asd.Where(c => c.subj == keyword);

    //Return the materialised list now:
    return View(asd.ToList());
}
```

Why would you want to do this?

1. You may often have a much more complicated where clause to apply and this way is much easier to code.
2. This method may be slightly more efficient as the compound where clause is not being passed to your data store when it's not required.

Comment: Ohhh i see, thanks for the info. This is very helpful